# How convert string type from Go to C binding?

Tags: go

I have C struct:

```
struct sanlk_lockspace {
   char name[48];
}
```

and go-code:

```
/*
#include ....
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    ls := C.struct_sanlk_lockspace{name: C.CString("lockspace_11")}
}
```

As result, I see error:

```
   cannot use _Cfunc_CString("lockspace_11") (type *_Ctype_char) 
   as type [48]_Ctype_char in field value
```

How to convert the string type correctly? ?

Comment: If this structure is related to https://pagure.io/sanlock/blob/master/f/src/sanlock.h it's missing a few fields. Not noted in this header is whether `name` is always \0-terminated; contrast this with the comment at line 55 about `char path[SANLK_PATH_LEN]`.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it's not working because [48]_Ctype_char is a very different structure than *_Ctype_char.

In Go, an array is quite different from most other languages. An array in Go is more like a struct with numeric property identifiers. In C, an array is a pointer to a specific type, but where it is known to the developer that additional instances of that type are in contiguous memory after the 0th element. In Go, a string is a struct with two attributes, `Data` and `Len`. The `Data` attribute is more like what C knows as an array or string. The `Len` attribute is the number of contiguous instances of the unit-type.

The trouble you're having is that a struct of 48 fields, all c::char, is not assignable with a pointer to an instance of c::char. The fact that 47 allocations exist contiguous with that single instance is something you as the developer know, but it is a fact concerning which the Go compiler is quite unconvinced.

The simplest cast you could do would be to declare a specific type as a struct with `{Data *_Ctype_char; Len uintptr}`, and assign the value with Data as the literal result, and Len is the number of instances of _Ctype_char values that can be read before encountering `_Ctype_char(0)`.

To convert that to a string, you would have to convert the single-byte _Ctype_Char to a multi-byte unicode character, of Go-type `glyph` for each element of that sequence.

At the point that you have a Go instance of a struct with a pointer to glyph and a uintptr sized number, it can be converted to a Go-type String. The reverse would be to convert each contiguous glyph back to its uint8 correlative, if one exists, optionally implementing some strategy to losslessly convert, and cap it with a `uint8(0)` if the original was not preserved. That *uint8, which the compiler now has no record as to size, is compatible with *_Ctype_char, and can be written back to a C-type string.

Comment: Technically, a C array is still an array. It's just that in many contexts it "decays", as we like to say, to a pointer. When embedded into a C struct though, it remains an array until you try to use the struct element. The main problem I see here is we don't know whether `char name[48];` will be used *as* a C *string*, or whether it will be used as 48 individual `char`s, and whether we should zero-out some of the elements as `strncpy` would, or not. These aren't discoverable from the type, only from documentation or other code.

Comment: Hmm. I mean, at assembly, it's only contiguous chars at a memory location, with the invariant presumed that it will be ended with a NUL char. It might be different since C99, but I don't remember C having any special behavior for arrays or strings, once you fall out of the context wherein malloc was called. I'm not saying you're wrong, @Torek, but I am saying that I don't understand what that means in context of my memories of working with C, or from my experience of FFI in context of Rust and Python (I've not used Go's FFI outside of toy scripts).

Comment: The TL;DR is that when you see an array of char in C you can't tell how to *use* it without further information. Based on https://marc.info/?l=sanlock-devel&m=135744747431649 it looks like it's treated as a a possibly-non-NUL-terminated (strncpy or strncat stype) not-quite-string. If you fill all 48 bytes with nonzero `char`s you have a non-C-string datum that requires 49 bytes to hold as a C string, or 48 bytes plus a count to hold as a Go string.

Comment: This predates even ANSI C: directory entries in a V6 file system were 2 bytes of inode number and 14 bytes for file name, with zero-padding if the name was not 14 bytes long. That's what the `strncpy` function does, which surprises many C programmers who don't expect `strncpy(a, b, len)` to write `len` bytes to `a` if b is a valid but short C string of, say, `len-100000` characters.